# Change Document Set name on creation

Tags: 2013, document-library, document-set

SP2013. User creates Document Set, **Name** field is hided. After user pressed **Save** button Document Set item has to have name like `"<ID> document set"`. What's the best scenario to achive this?

Comment: Is it on-prem or sharepoint online?

Comment: on-premise installation